# Difference between "provocative" and "thought-provoking"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nuance

In some dictionaries, *provocative* has two meanings:

> (1) Causing annoyance, anger, or another strong reaction, especially deliberately.
> (2) Arousing sexual desire or interest

Some other dictionaries include one additional meaning:

> (3) adj. Thought-provoking

The discussion is now focused on the third meaning, which I believe to be derived from the first meaning.

However, in my decades of experience in US and Canada, I find that, when we are using the third meaning, we exclusively mean that someone is being "**thought-provoking by trying to cause anger** or a strong emotion".

Is it correct that, one can be thought-provoking by many methods, and being provocative is just one of them?

For one example, when we say a presentation is using provocative language, we usually mean that language caused an emotional spike, usually with a slightly negative sense.

For another example, a native speaker once said:

> You can be thought-provoking without being provocative.

I've never seen a single case when the word *provocative* is used to describe a person in a 100% positive context.

Comment: I've seen essays where the term, "a provocative idea might be" and this is in your third sense. This is usually in written texts. I would say verbally, the first two would dominate.

Comment: Differentiate between what a dictionary defines and how people use a term. We all discriminate between good and bad, and so admire a discriminating taste. But in housing and jobs, we argue against discriminating.

Answer (score 5):

Meanings of *provocative* tend towards the negative but are not necessarily so.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provocative)
> 1 causing thought about interesting subjects:
> *The programme will take a detailed and provocative look at the problem of homelessness.*
> 2 causing an angry reaction, usually intentionally:
> *a provocative question/remark*
> *In a deliberately provocative speech, she criticized the whole system of government.*
> 3 If behaviour or clothing is provocative, it is intended to cause sexual desire:
> *She slowly leaned forward in a provocative way.*
> 4 intended to cause a reaction, esp. anger or annoyance, or to force you to think more carefully about something:
> *a provocative speech*
> *provocative advertisements*

Merriam Webster is briefer:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provocative)
> provocative, adjective:
> serving or tending to provoke, excite, or stimulate
> *a provocative question*

There are therefore at least two veins of meaning: provoking strong or sexual reactions; and stimulating something such as thought or more careful consideration. The second vein is not necessarily negative and even Merriam Webster recognises its usage in the US.

Hence, *thought-provoking* may be seen as a restricted sense of *provocative*, one limited to the stimulation of thought rather than of behavioural, angry, sexual or other reactions.

Completely positive views of *provocative* may be found. To take just one example, in the following the writer views *provocative* as a good characteristic, stimulating people to think positively.

> [Diresta](https://www.diresta.com/knockoutpresentationsblog/are-your-presentation-titles-provocative-enough)
>
> "Are Your Presentation Titles Provocative Enough?"
> *... The event attracted a large crowd and the energy was positive and upbeat. The informal comments very positive and even the few men who attended liked my presentation. It was determined that there was nothing negative about my speech. There was even positive buzz the next day ..."*